# Properly validate the JSON.parsed data in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, if-statement, conditional-statements, javascript-objects

I'm creating a small module for the angular and I'm stuck with condition where I check my JSON.parsed data if they're correct.

```
read(): Position|null {
    try {
        ...
        let parsedData  = JSON.parse(data);
        if (parsedData && parsedData.x && parsedData.y)
            return new Position(parsedData.x, parsedData.y);
    } catch (e) {
        ...
    }
    return null;
}
```

It seems like not a great solution to me as if there's more properties in the object I previously stringified, then I'd need to check for each one of them. I'm also not sure about what happens when the parsed data are `null`. Is there any other solution for checking the strigified data? Thanks

Comment: This seems like a very reasonable solution. What is your concern exactly? If the JSON you are parsing has other fields it won't affect the logic you've written above. And you wrapped the parse in a try-catch which should also handle any malformed JSON cases.

Comment: I'm concerned about changing the object I store in JSON in the future. In case I'll need to change the object and expect more properties from parsed object, then I'd need to check for every property if it's set. I was thinking about checking the instance of parsed data, but it probably wouldn't work as when I stringify the Position object and then parse it back it's not an instance of Position anymore, am I right?

Comment: If your json string is already a serialized Position object, you really don't need to make any checks. You could just **return JSON.parse(data) as Position**

Comment: that's what I was looking for, thank you. Maybe you should consider wrapping it up and make an answer for that question so I can mark it as correct. Thanks once again

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To convert your json result to a `Position` object you simply need to cast it like so:

```
read(): Position|null {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(data) as Position;
    } catch (e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

However casting won't perform any kind of validation. It won't know if the json data actually has any of the fields you expect `Position` to have. For that you'll unfortunately need to verify each field manually.

One easy-ish way to do that would be to keep a list of your properties in your class and then test if the object has those fields after you cast it:

```
class Position {
    public x: Number;
    public y: Number;
    public someOtherField: string;
    
    public static PropertyNames: string[] = ["x", "y", "someOtherField"];
    public static isValid(pos: Position): Boolean {
        return Position.PropertyNames.every((i) => pos && pos.hasOwnProperty(i));
    }
}

let obj = new Position();
alert(Position.isValid(obj)); //false

obj.x = null;
obj.y = null;
obj.someOtherField = null;

alert(Position.isValid(obj)); //true
```

Comment: The question is about validating. This answer provides no validation at all.

Comment: That is correct. I believe OP said he would do the checks after the typecasting and wasn't sure how to cast a generic Object to the Position type without needing to instantiate it using 'new'. And he explicitly asked me to add that as the solution for this question.

Comment: That is true, according to the discussion, but it does not do the title and question justice. Keep in mind that SO should also serve visitors as a knowledge base.
A good solution would be updating the answer or making it more general.

Comment: I added validation code now